# Android Fragments in Recyclerview ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I need to place a lot of different views where some of them need to be fragments in a Recyclerview. For example a MapFragment or a YoutubePlayerFragment.

Is there a good way to place them into viewholders for the recycler view so that the references are not leaking or should I simply not use a Recyclerview therefore? (the list can get very long, it's a message timeline in a messenger)

I'm using the MVP pattern so every the Fragments will have presenters that have to get recycled somehow aswell but that's a minor problem. The Bigger problem is to handle the lifecycle events of the fragments in the viewholders.

Comment: [Look at this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/embedding-custom-views-with-mapview-v2/)

Comment: This can be done but it would be very messy. It would be very difficult to interact with various elements inside the fragments they are all of different types. Better idea would be to make a recyclerview of buttons which on click launch the various fragments.